# The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything

Tags: apache2

Output of config test was:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 216 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/nagios3.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
dpkg: error processing package openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first error: output of config test was:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 216 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/nagios3.conf: No such file or directory Action 'configtest' failed.
```

**My Answer:**

I reconfigured the resolv.conf file using `vi /etc/resolv.conf` and set the dns ip so that the system is now able to resolve the host, and now the system is not showing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have installed nagios, then enabled the nagios web interface, and then uninstalled nagios? This has resulted in a dangling symlink `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/nagios3.conf`. You should be able to confirm if it is dangling using the ls command.

If it is dangling indeed, then just `rm /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/nagios3.conf` and then apache should work as expected. And just in case, check if there are any other dangling symlinks in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/`.

Comment: it is good help, but it is still showing the same problem.....

Comment: Is it still complaining about nagios3.conf or about something else? Can you post `ls -la /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/*`. As well, which version of ubuntu is this running on?